# Java - Automatic updates from S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-s3

I have my Java application all set and working. But I will need to include Auto-updating feature where files are scheduled to be downloaded from AWS Bucket. I was planning to make use of AWS SDK for this functionality, but this library seems to add up extra 7MB to the installer size.

Is there any way I can add this functionality without the use of AWS SDK library?, or Use the same library but not let it take so much of size with the installer?

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways around that:

- Access the file directly over HTTP (see S3 GetObject)
- Create an "Uber JAR" with only the classes you need, providing you don't load classes by reflection.

And of course, consider if such workaround is worthy the 7MB...